# adding a counter based on how many items displayed using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I want to add a counter in my displayed items. As you can see in the image below, there's a `count should be here`, I'm not pertaining the ID since it is auto-incrementing and I have a delete function so as I said it's not the ID but on how many items are in the database and on how many items are being fetched in the card.

I want to replace in the `count should be here` to `1` and `2` since there is two but it should increment if there are more displayed and so on.

[image]

so basically this is my query.

```
<?php 
    include 'includes/connection_operation.php';
    $sqlRepository = "SELECT * FROM tbl_repository WHERE research_status = 'Active'";
    $sqlQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRepository);
    $getNumRows = mysqli_num_rows($sqlQuery);
    if($getNumRows > 0 ){
        while ($fetchRepository = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)){
            $thumbpic = $fetchRepository['research_thumbnail'];
            include 'card_recentlyuploaded.php';
        }
        
    }
```

and this is the code for the card, where I display the fetched items from the database.

card_recentlyuploaded.php

```
<div class="container d-flex" style="padding-top: 15px;">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <span style="display:inline-block; padding-top: 15px;">counter should be here</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 15rem;">
            <div>
                <a class="fancybox" href="admin/files/Images/<?php echo $thumbpic; ?>">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="admin/files/Images/<?php echo $thumbpic; ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center"><?php echo $fetchRepository['research_title'] ?></h5>
                <p class="card-text">Date added: <span><?php echo $fetchRepository['document_added'] ?></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, what have you tried so far? Wouldn't it just be `num_rows` that you already have?

Comment: Add `$num = 1;` before your `while`-loop. Then you just need to replace the current text with: `<?= $num++ ?>` which will echo the value of `$num` and then increment it by one.

Comment: You mean a counter, like 1, 2 , 3... ? Just put a `$ctr=1;` outside your loop, then `$ctr++;` inside your loop. Then in `card_recentlyuploaded.php` reference it with `<?php echo $ctr;?>`

Answer (score 1):

as what user `Magnus Eriksson` and `Kinglish` suggested in the comment. This is the working   code for anyone's reference.

this is my query.

```
<?php 
    include 'includes/connection_operation.php';
    $sqlRepository = "SELECT * FROM tbl_repository WHERE research_status = 'Active'";
    $sqlQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlRepository);
    $getNumRows = mysqli_num_rows($sqlQuery);
    $counter = 1;
    if($getNumRows > 0 ){
        while ($fetchRepository = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery)){
            $thumbpic = $fetchRepository['research_thumbnail'];
            include 'card_recentlyuploaded.php';
            $counter++;
        }
        
    }
```

cards_recentlyuploaded.php

```
<div class="container d-flex" style="padding-top: 15px;">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <span style="display:inline-block; padding-top: 15px;"><?php echo $counter;?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="card h-100" style="width: 15rem;">
            <div>
                <a class="fancybox" href="admin/files/Images/<?php echo $thumbpic; ?>">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="admin/files/Images/<?php echo $thumbpic; ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title text-center"><?php echo $fetchRepository['research_title'] ?></h5>
                <p class="card-text">Date added: <span><?php echo $fetchRepository['document_added'] ?></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```